# My post edit rejected after 3 hours by Community♦ as conflicted with a subsequent edit

Tags: support, review-queues, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

I have edited [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40001119/dynamically-change-the-javascript-event-handler) post to improve formatting at `2016-10-12 14:34:04Z` and that was rejected after 3 hours (`2016-10-12 17:23:50Z`) by Community♦ as conflicted with a subsequent edit.

See my edit status [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13961621).

I know that, if the full privileged user or owner of the post start editing at the same time I have started and submitted after I have submitted will result in conflict with a subsequent edit for me. But in my case, 2 users approved my edit and then after 3 hours it was rejected because of full privileged user edit.

Is it possible after 3 hours or is it a bug?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The question ended up in [the Help and Improvement review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/helper/13962221), where someone saw the same problems you did and made more or less the same fixes. See: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/40001119/timeline